# Spring Boot content-negotiation configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have difficulties configuring content-negotiation with spring-boot.
I would like to keep most of the default spring-boot configuration.
I followed the following  https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc/
not so recent tutorial. At the moment when I send a request for `application/json` or `txt/html` the view doesn't seem to get resolved, but when I turn on `@EnableWebMvc` it does seem to get resolved.
Below is my current configuration.

```
@Configuration // according to the spring-boot docs this should be enough with spring-boot
//@EnableWebMvc  If I enable this content-negotiation seems to work without any configuration, but I loose the default spring-boot configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean(name = "jsonViewResolver")
    public ViewResolver getJsonViewResolver() {
        return new JsonViewResolver();
    }


    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    // Simple strategy: only path extension is taken into account
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = newContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not registering your resolvers in your content negotiation manager.

please try with the following modification:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager){
  ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = newContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
  resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
  List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();
  ViewResolver aViewResolver = getJsonViewResolver();
  resolvers.add(aViewResolver);
  resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
  return resolver;
}
```